# Custom loss function for predicting interget outputs?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I'm currenly working on a dataset where I've to predict an integer output. It starts from 1 to N. I've build a network with loss function mse. But I feel like mse loss function may not be an ideal loss function to minimize in the case of integer output.

I'm also round my prediction to get integer output. Is there a way to make/optimize the model better in case of integer output.

Can anyone provide some help on how to deal with integer output/targets. This is the loss function I'm using right now.

```
model.compile(optimizer=SGD(0.001), loss='mse')
```

Comment: Ist the distance between the outputs meaningful, or only the order of the outputs? If the latter is true you could look into ordinal regression  https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/23233/cost-function-for-ordinal-regression-using-neural-networks

Comment: @JohannesAck I didn't get what you meant. The targets here are months. Yes there's a order here if that's what you mean.

Comment: Ah, so ordinal regression is not the way to go here. 
In general, there's nothing wrong with doing it the way you are, by using mse and rounding the output, I'm actually relatively sure that this is optimal. 

This again depends on the details of your task, but it might make sense to transform your labels to a representation that accounts for the cyclical nature of months, i.e. Dec to Jan is one month, but 12 -1 = 11. [Here is a blog post outlining this a bit more](http://blog.davidkaleko.com/feature-engineering-cyclical-features.html)
I hope this helps, otherwise please add more details.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong loss, mean squared error is a loss for regression, and you have a classification problem (discrete outputs, not continuous).

So for this your model should have a softmax output layer:

```
model.add(Dense(N, activation="softmax"))
```

And you should be using a classification loss:

```
model.compile(optimizer=SGD(0.001), loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy')
```

Assuming your labels are integers in the `[0, N-1]` range (off by one), this should work. To make a prediction, you should do:

```
output = np.argmax(model.predict(some_data), axis=1) + 1
```

The `+1` is because integer labels go from `0` to `N-1`

Comment: Actually, my output is continuous but are integers. I mean I'm predict number of months column. It could range from 1 month to all the way upto 1000 months or more. But the problem here is in regression it's usually continuous isn't but I require integer output that's why I don't know which loss function would result in better prediction.

Comment: Depending on the size of the dataset and the value of N, this could go horribly wrong, especially when target values that are numerically close are also similar in whatever domain they come from

Comment: @user_12 Integers are discrete, not continuous, what does continuous mean to you?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Sorry. That was a mistake. So, should I treat this as a classification problem? I read online that some are suggesting to use regression in this case but I don't know the correct way to deal with this problem

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro If I treat this as a classification problem won't this cause issues when predicting on new datapoints? It will only able to predict what is seen? Won't this cause problems.

Comment: @user_12 What do you mean predict what is seen?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro In a classification problem, won't it predict upto N categories which is in train dataset only.

Comment: @user_12 yes but thats a problem in any model, not specific to classification

Comment: I'm trying to predict when will a person leave his current job based on the data given. So is classification the right way to approach this problem?

Comment: @user_12 That is something you have to try and find out experimentally.

Answer (score 1):

[Ordinal regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_regression) could be an appropriate approach, in case predicting the wrong month but close to the true month is considered a smaller mistake than predicting a value one year earlier or later. Only you can know that, based on the specific problem you want to solve.

I found an implementation of the appropriate loss function [on github](https://github.com/JHart96/keras_ordinal_categorical_crossentropy) (no affiliation). For completeness, below I copy-paste the code from that repo:

```
from keras import backend as K
from keras import losses

def loss(y_true, y_pred):
    weights = K.cast(
        K.abs(K.argmax(y_true, axis=1) - K.argmax(y_pred, axis=1))/(K.int_shape(y_pred)[1] - 1),
        dtype='float32'
    )
    return (1.0 + weights) * losses.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
```

Comment: Actually it's fine I get wrong month but close to true month it's a small mistake. How should I prepare my targets for this loss function? Should I provide one hot encoded vectors of target (or) just like [1, 5, 7, 250, 397, 500, 750] like asingle vector?

Comment: @user_12 the function above uses one-hot encoded targets

Comment: I'm trying to predict when will a person leave his current job based on the data given. So is classification the right way to approach this problem?